# How to install my Intel graphics updates

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

As per image displayed here, it always shows me an untrusted package when installing my Intel Graphics updates. Are there any ideas on how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Please show the actual error message.

Answer (score 2):

VAAPI driver for Intel G45 & HD Graphics family (*i965-va-driver*) which is shown in your screenshot is in the default Ubuntu repositories for all supported versions of Ubuntu, and it will be updated like any other Ubuntu package by the Software Updater.